# Types of work done on a cart rolling down an incline

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction, work

When a cart rolls down an incline what types of work are done on the cart? I know gravity does work on the cart but does the normal force, friction or air resistance do work on the cart too?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of work is:

\begin{align}
W = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{\Delta d}
\end{align}

Where $\vec{F}$ is a force on an object, $\vec{\Delta d}$ is the displacement of the object and $W$ is the work done on the object by the force $\vec{F}$.

The important thing to note is that we are dealing with vectors and we have a dot product in our definition. Recall that if two vectors are perpendicular their dot product (by definition) is zero.

If the force is acting in a direction perpendicular to the displacement of the object then the work is zero. Now let's analyze our four forces acting on the cart:

1. **Gravity**: Force is acting down. Displacement is not horizontal (because sliding down a ramp) so work is **non-zero**.
2. **Friction/Air Resistance**: These forces always "slow down" our object. This is because the force is in the opposite direction of the cart's motion. This is not perpendicular (180 degrees not 90 or 270) so work is the opposite direction of the cart's motion. This is not perpendicular (180 degrees not 90 or 270) so work is **non-zero**.
3. **Normal force**: This force perpendicular to the ramp. The cart rolls along the ramp so the force is perpendicular to the displacement so the work done is **zero**.

Hopefully this helps. If not, please ask questions to clarify.